# Об употреблении "либо", "или", "не", "вместе с тем"

Tags: семантика

Предположим, что на столике лежат туз, король, дама, валет.

Верно ли, что:

- указание "Возьми туза или даму; вместе с тем, не бери туза, или не бери даму." означает указание "Возьми либо туза, либо даму.",
- указание "Возьми туза, короля или даму; вместе с тем, не бери ни туза ни короля, или не бери ни туза ни даму, или не бери ни короля ни даму." означает указание "Возьми либо туза, либо короля, либо даму."?

P.S. Дорогие филологи, если я допустил ошибки (например, в пунктуации), тогда поправьте меня.

Answer (score 1):

Это был перевод с помощью транслятора?  Тогда сам перевод некорректный, нужны исходники. Если это не перевод, то сами высказывания полный бред, т. к. сами себе противоречат. Скорректируйте их.
Пример исправления Ваших высказываний с точки зрения пунктуации (менее бредовыми они от этого не становятся):

1. указание "Возьми туза или даму, но
       не бери туза или не бери даму."
2. указание "Возьми туза, короля или даму:

   - не бери ни туза, ни короля;
   - не бери ни туза, ни даму;
   - не бери ни короля, ни даму."

Comment: Спасибо за предоставленные сведения.